# How to pad the values of a input? Credit/Debit Card input style

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building the UI for a payment page, using React mostly. How do I separate the card numbers in groups of 4 while the user is typing them?

Edit: Extra libraries or packages are ok, but I am looking for actual code solutions, without having to add dependencies.

Comment: using a npm or yarn package that does that for you :) ( hint :  search on google : npm card number input )

Comment: @MihaiT Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a pure javascript, or React solution. Because I don't want to add another dependency, I want to know how do I do it. I check some jQuery answer here, but then again, I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: Well. If you want us to give you a solution. Try it yourself first. Then post here whatever code you came up with. And we will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use any external library then use a regular expression.
For Ex.

```
var value = '1234567891234562'
var new_value = value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').trim();
console.log(new_value);
output: 1234 5678 9123 4562
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin! Didn't thought of RegEx, was complicating things way too much. But your answer is perfect.